# Count of grep matching only "file" is greater than 3

Tags: shell

My file looks as

```
{file} {tag} {comment} {dateModified}
file1         comment1
file2     2   comment2
file3     3
file10
file11
xmlfile5
xmlfile6
```

How to compare if count of grep matching only "file" is greater than 3 then get first record in this case v1

Comment: What is v1? and what is ``matching only "file"``? Is it filename that contains word "file"?

Comment: Thank you for response. Sorry not v1, it should return file1. Its Text that contains file.

Comment: Thank you for response. Sorry not v1, it should return file1. It should differentiate between text "file" and "xmlfile".Since file is repeating 5 times, it should return file1

Comment: If the matches count is not greater than 3? And do you really need to use ``grep``?

Comment: Only if count is greater than 5 then get file1, else nothing. Grep is not necessary. it should work in Karaf script